# How to know and find all emails in Magento?

Tags: email, templates, magento

I need to find out where are all emails templates (newsletter, registration confirmation, etc..) to customize **AND** and translate them.

Where can I find an exhaustive list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a pretty good list from *System > Transactional Emails > Add New Template > Load default template*.

Also just about all emails start out in the folder `app/locale/en_US/template/email/`